# Datajoint LabBook - how to change ports

Tags: datajoint

I am running Datajoint LabBook through the provided docker container (https://datajoint.github.io/datajoint-labbook/user.html#installation) and wondered whether there is a way to move it away from the (default?) port (80?). I am not sure I understand the instructions in the .yaml (docker-compose-deploy.yaml), it seems to me that there is a pharus endpoint (5000) and then there are two port definitions (443:443, 80:80) further down. I am not sure what those refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can move the DataJoint LabBook service to a different port, however, a few changes will be necessary for it to function properly.

### TL;DR

Assuming that you are accessing DataJoint LabBook locally, follow these steps:

1. Add the line `127.0.0.1 fakeservices.datajoint.io` to your `hosts` file. Verify the `hosts` file [location in your file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system).
2. Modify the `ports` configuration in `docker-compose-deploy.yaml` as:

```yaml
ports:
  - "3000:443" # replace 3000 with the port of your choosing
  #- "80:80" # disables HTTP -> HTTPS redirect
```

3. Navigate in your Google Chrome browser to `https://fakeservices.datajoint.io:3000`

### Detailed Explanation

Let me first speak a bit on the architecture and then describe the relevant changes as we go along.

Below is the [Docker Compose file](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-labbook/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-deploy.yaml) presented in the documentation. I'll make the assumption that you are attempting to run this locally.

```yaml
# PHARUS_VERSION=0.1.0 DJLABBOOK_VERSION=0.1.0 docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yaml pull
# PHARUS_VERSION=0.1.0 DJLABBOOK_VERSION=0.1.0 docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yaml up -d
#
# Intended for production deployment.
# Note: You must run both commands above for minimal outage.
# Make sure to add an entry into your /etc/hosts file as `127.0.0.1 fakeservices.datajoint.io`
# This serves as an alias for the domain to resolve locally.
# With this config and the configuration below in NGINX, you should be able to verify it is
# running properly by navigating in your browser to `https://fakeservices.datajoint.io`.
# If you don't update your hosts file, you will still have access at `https://localhost`
# however it should simply display 'Not secure' since the cert will be invalid.
version: "2.4"
x-net: &net
  networks:
      - main
services:
  pharus:
    <<: *net
    image: datajoint/pharus:${PHARUS_VERSION}
    environment:
      - PHARUS_PORT=5000
  fakeservices.datajoint.io:
    <<: *net
    image: datajoint/nginx:v0.0.16
    environment:
      - ADD_zlabbook_TYPE=STATIC
      - ADD_zlabbook_PREFIX=/
      - ADD_pharus_TYPE=REST
      - ADD_pharus_ENDPOINT=pharus:5000
      - ADD_pharus_PREFIX=/api
      - HTTPS_PASSTHRU=TRUE
    entrypoint: sh
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        rm -R /usr/share/nginx/html
        curl -L $$(echo "https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-labbook/releases/download/\
            ${DJLABBOOK_VERSION}/static-djlabbook-${DJLABBOOK_VERSION}.zip" | tr -d '\n' | \
            tr -d '\t') -o static.zip
        unzip static.zip -d /usr/share/nginx
        mv /usr/share/nginx/build /usr/share/nginx/html
        rm static.zip
        /entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      pharus:
        condition: service_healthy
networks:
  main:
```

First, the `Note` in the header comment above is important and seems to have been missed in the DataJoint LabBook documentation (I've filed this [issue](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-labbook/issues/145) to update it). Make sure to follow the instruction in the `Note` as 'secure' access is [required from pharus](https://datajoint.github.io/pharus/pharus.html#pharus.server.login) (more on this below).

From the Docker Compose file, you will note 2 services:

- `pharus` - A DataJoint REST API backend service. This service is configured to listen on port `5000`, however, it is not actually exposed to the host. This means that it will not conflict and does not require any change as it is entirely contained within a local, virtual docker network.
- `fakeservices.datajoint.io` - A proxying service that is exposed to the host and thus accessible locally and publicly against the host. Its primary purpose is to either:

  a) forward requests beginning with `/api` to `pharus`, or

  b) resolve other requests to the DataJoint LabBook GUI.

  DataJoint LabBook's GUI is a static web app which means that it can be served as insecure (HTTP, typically port `80`) and secure (HTTPS, typically port `443`). Because of the secure requirement from `pharus`, requests made to port `80` are simply redirected to `443` and exposed for convenience. Therefore, if we want to move DataJoint LabBook to a new port we simply should change the mapping of `443` to a new port on the host and disable the `80 -> 443` redirect. Therefore, the port update would look like so:

```yaml
ports:
  - "3000:443" # replace 3000 with the port of your choosing
  #- "80:80" # disables HTTP -> HTTPS redirect
```

Finally, after configuring and bringing up the services, you should be able to confirm the port change by navigating to `https://fakerservices.datajoint.io:3000` in your Google Chrome browser.